# Integrate Amazon IFrame in Drupal webpage

Tags: iframe, amazon-web-services, drupal-7

I would like to integrate an iframe like :

```
<iframe src="http://rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" border="0" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

into drupal block in the content of webpage. The problem that i get an empty HTML in the IFrame body. I tried all kind of other iframes an it works, but not this from Amazon. Any ideas please?!

Comment: The URL you specified returns a 403 Forbidden error from the server. Are you using the correct parameters required by Amazon for your real implementation?

Comment: Hier is the original iframe in question:
`<iframe src="http://rcm-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=schlagerporta-21&o=3&p=48&l=st1&mode=music-de&search=helene fischer&fc1=000000&lt1=_blank&lc1=3366FF&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" border="0" frameborder="0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Comment: I just pasted your code in a Drupal block content area and it shows an Amazon leaderboard in german. I used no trick other than specify Full Html for the text filter. If it doesn't work for you, it's probably something site-specific.